# Is it safe to display PayPal Client Secret in the html?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-subscriptions

I am trying to integrate PayPal Subscription API to my website and there is this line of code in the html
`<script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id={{client_id}}&vault=true&intent=subscription">`.

And that made me curious if it is really safe to put my Client Secret there, where everyone would able to see it through dev tools

Answer (score 1):

The PayPal JS SDK must always be loaded with a `client-id` value, as documented. That is the purpose of this value.

---

A [REST App](https://developer.paypal.com/dashboard/applications)'s `secret`, which is a different value, should never be used in any client-side code such as HTML or public JS.